# open a link within android app instead of open a webview

Tags: java, android, android-intent, webview

I am trying to open a social link within my app on a button click listener.i want to open it within app i do not want to open a webview for it. I dont find any way to open that link.the url for this link is come from server also i dont understand how to load url on a button click.Please provide any solution.

```
this.linkedin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           String URL=sbobj.getLinkdin_url();
           Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LinkedinProfile.class);
           intent.putExtra("URL",sbobj.getLinkdin_url());
           startActivity(intent);
       }
});
```

`sbobj` is the object of class from which I am trying to get url.

```
"linkdin_url": "https://in.linkedin.com/in/kumaraguru"
```

this is the url,which i have to get from server.

Answer (score 4):

Custom Tab layout will work for you.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

```
this.linkedin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String URL = sbobj.getLinkdin_url();
                CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(URL));

            }
        });
```

Comment: That's Nice..!!

Comment: Do i need to put any dependency for customTabIntent it gives me error can not resolve the symbol CustomTabIntent  also launchUrl method.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.0+'
will work. Add the latest one

Comment: This code also do not solve mine problem as code u suggest also ask for login again and again for each list item.I need if i login once then another time when i select another item(link in list) would not ask for login again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
this.linkedin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           String url = sbobj.getLinkdin_url();
                            if (url.contains("https://in.linkedin.com")) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                                startActivity(i);
                            } else {
                                Utils.ShowToast(context, "Url not Valid!");
                            }
       }
});
```

Comment: Do i need to make one another activity to display this url or it will open the link without need of any other activity.

Comment: No it will open LinkedIn app if installed otherwise open in browser.

Comment: You don't need to implement Other activity to open this URL.

Comment: It means if i want to open any other profie too like facebook profile or twitter profile by using link then it is important to have these apps in phone so that it will directly open their profile otherwise it will jump to browser ?

Comment: Yes I think it will open Because this code i used for open map so i don't have more idea about this.

Comment: One more question why it is not directly jump to that person profile code u suggest me is working but problem is that it open the linkedin and ask for login first so that it display that person profile i dont need this i want to direct open that url of linkedin without any login.

Comment: In browser you don't need to login.

Comment: In app you must be need login.

Comment: So you mean if same work i will do in website then it will directly open that profile but if i will do this in app then i need to login first to my account ?

Comment: Yes you will need to login firs because app not open without login.

Comment: OK Thank you.It helps me.

Comment: hlo...as i used the code u suggested to me it always jump to browser and ask again and again to login means if i will open link 10 times then it will ask 10 time login.and when i press back button it first jump to login screen and then on again back press it actual reach to exact activity. Give me any solution to solve it.

Comment: Okay let me check what is issue.

Comment: Hello This is happen from linked in side because linked in not allow to view other profile without login so you must be need login in linked in.

Comment: i am getting this parameter in recycler view i have a list of link so it is not good to login for ever link item of recycler view. because if i will login for first then again when i will click on second list item then it will again ask for login. Suggest me something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with adding new activity then you better use this. I will beautiful Webview out of box and very easy to use but yes you need to add one more activity.
Here is the link: [FinestWebView](https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android). See the beautiful UI of this:

[image]

Comment: i actually do not want to use web view in my app. please suggest me something else.